# Cannot send to the browser ByteArrayOutputStream in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, pivot4j

I have the following code in Play for Scala that attempts to send an Excel file to the browser:

```
            val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream
            val exporter = new org.pivot4j.ui.poi.ExcelExporter(out)
            val renderer = new TableRenderer
            renderer.render(model, exporter);
            out.flush
            out.close
            Ok(out).withHeaders(
                  CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                  CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename = file.xlsx")
```

The `Ok` throws a compilation error:

> ◾Cannot write an instance of java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream to HTTP
>   response. Try to define a Writeable[java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream]

Even though `ByteArrayOutputStream` is of type output, it cannot be written. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `toByteArray` on `out` like so:

```
Ok(out.toByteArray).withHeaders(...)
```

[DefaultWritables](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/Writeable.scala#L64) provides a list of `Writable` provided by Play out-of-the-box. In particular, there exists [Writeable[Array[Byte]]](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/Writeable.scala#L177) which should get picked up when you call `toByteArray`

Comment: It compiles, but it throws the following message when it runs: `[warn] p.c.s.n.NettyModelConversion - Content-Type set both in header (application/vnd.ms-excel) and attached to entity (application/octet-stream), ignoring content type from entity. To remove this warning, use Result.as(...) to set the content type, rather than setting the header manually.`

Comment: I made it work with `Ok(out.toByteArray)` without the headers

Comment: If you still wish to set `Content-Type` header try `.as("application/vnd.ms-excel")` instead of `.withHeaders`.